# Interface with code - i can't use overloading method Map for collection

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Here is example of code:
[https://dotnetfiddle.net/D1lZ16]

i have error in line 15
Could someone please explain to me why and whether this is obvious?

when i use similar code with DI i my app. Everything works.

in Startup:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMapperService<AccountDto, Account>, AccountMapper>();
```

Service:

```
public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
    {
        private readonly IMapperService<AccountDto, Account> _accountMapper;

        public ApplicationService
        (

            IMapperService<AccountDto, Account> accountMapper
        )
        {
            _accountMapper = accountMapper;
        }
}
```

thank you for the explanations

Comment: Please add the relevant code here. External links may become inaccessible or the code there might change, making this question useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code closer, it seems you already found the issue, you can only access your `IEnumerable<TDestination> Map(IEnumerable<TSource> sources)` from the interface instance because it is not defined on the class.  Are you looking for an [abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) instead of interface?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var source =  new List<AccountDto>
            {
                new AccountDto { Id = 1, UserId = 1, Name = "private account", Description = "some desc", MinValue = -10000},
                new AccountDto { Id = 2, UserId = 1, Name = "company account", Description = "some desc", MinValue = 0}
            };
        
        var mapper = new AccountMapper();
        var resultWrong = mapper.Map(source);
        var resultOK = ((IMapperService<AccountDto, Account>)mapper).Map(source);
    }
}

public interface IMapperService<TSource, TDestination>
{
     TDestination Map(TSource source);
     IEnumerable<TDestination> Map(IEnumerable<TSource> sources)
     {
         return sources.Select(Map);
     }
}

public class AccountMapper : IMapperService<AccountDto, Account>
{
    public Account Map(AccountDto source)
    {
        return new Account
        {
            Id = source.Id,
            Name = source.Name,
            Description = source.Description,
            MinValue = source.MinValue,
        };
    }
}

public class AccountDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal MinValue { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal MinValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see error. but i don't udertand the reason. Look at my Interface. i have  mthod IEnumerable<TDestination> Map(IEnumerable<TSource> sources)
     {
         return sources.Select(Map);
     }   and I use map of collectiot to collection by _accountMapper.Map(someCollection) in code and it works ....why first of these lines doesn't work.:  var resultWrong = mapper.Map(source);
  var resultOK = ((IMapperService<AccountDto, Account>)mapper).Map(source);

Comment: @mangood, I have updated the answer.  You should update your question with the error message and the code in the fiddle.